# MySQL: Combine multiple rows (with null values) into one row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called code_status:

```
  Code     Message
    1     "Start"
    2     "In process"
    3     "Finish"
```

And another table called history

```
 ID   Code    Name      time_date
 1     2      Jon       1/2/15
 31    1      Abby      2/1/15
 12    3      Sara      3/3/15
 31    2      Abby      2/3/15
 31    3      Abby      2/5/15
 8     2      Max       1/22/15
```

I want to create an history_view with the following schema:

```
history_view (id, name, start_date, process_date, finish_date)
```

If the date is not given, it would just be NULL

So it would look like

```
ID   Name    start_date    process_date      finish_date
31   Abby     2/1/15          2/3/15           2/5/15
1    Jon      NULL            1/2/15            NULL
... etc
```

So i started off by doing :

```
CREATE VIEW history_view
AS SELECT h.id, h.name, 
(CASE WHEN h.code = 1 THEN time_date) AS start_date,
(CASE when h.code = 2 THEN time_date) AS process_date,
(CASE when h.code = 3 THEN time_date) AS finish_date
FROM history h;
```

I would get a result like the following below though:

```
ID   Name    start_date    process_date      finish_date
31   Abby     2/1/15         NULL               NULL
31   Abby      NULL          2/3/15             NULL
31   Abby      NULL          NULL             2/5/15
... ETC
```

Is there any way to consolidate the rows together ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `consolidate` you're referring to `aggregation`, you can use an aggregate function, such as `min`:

```
CREATE VIEW history_view
AS SELECT h.id, h.name, 
min(CASE WHEN h.code = 1 THEN time_date) AS start_date,
min(CASE when h.code = 2 THEN time_date) AS process_date,
min(CASE when h.code = 3 THEN time_date) AS finish_date
FROM history h
group by h.id, h.name;
```

Comment: what does a min(case) do exactly?

Comment: Combined with the `group by` clause it will show the first `time_date` value where the `code` is 1, for each id and name combination (in the case of your first case statement). In the second case statement, it will show the first `time_date` value where the `code` is 2, for each id and name combination. Because there is only one such row for each combination of [id, name, code] it doesn't matter whether you use `min`, `max`, etc. so long as you use an aggregate function.